# Copy information from one column to another with a condition

Tags: mysql, sql, phone-number

I have the following table
I want the PHONE NUMBER column information to be copied to the OLD PHONE NUMBER column provided the US telephone format is followed
[FORMAT USA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iUkkc.jpg)

[MY TABLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qNDyL.jpg)

Comment: Please don’t link to images. Include all necessary information directly in your question, as editable text

Answer (score 0):

You could just check which rows have a valid phone number and dann asign them in a single update like this:

```
UPDATE SET OLD_PHONE_NUMBER = PHONE_NUMBER WHERE PHONE_NUMBER REGEXP '^\([0-9]{3}\) [0-9]{3}\-[0-9]{4}$'
```